# Project not finding my reusable app's admin template override

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have a reusable app with a directory structure like this:

```
myapp/
  myapp/
    views.py
    models.py
    ...etc

    templates/
      myapp/
        template1.html
        ...etc
      admin/
        index.html
  test/
    ...testing stuff
  setup.py
  ...etc
```

I'm overriding the `index.html` admin template so that I can add some additional links in `{% block userlinks %}` that will appear in a project's navigation when it uses my app.

However, when using my app inside a project, the admin homepage still uses Django's own `index.html` file. The project itself has a `base_site.html` that it uses, but the template inheritance diagram (in `django-debug-toolbar`) looks like this:

```
/path/to/virtualenv/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html
/projectpath/projectname/templates/admin/base_site.html
/path/to/virtualenv/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html
```

...that first entry should be the `index.html` file in my app's templates directory! Does anyone know why it's not being found? I can post settings if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's template loader looks for templates in the order that apps are defined in `INSTALLED_APPS`. In your case you must have defined `django.contrib.admin` ahead of your app, so Django will always look there first and use the first template it finds.

Change it so that your app is first in the list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
]
```